# Trying to get Google Scatter Chart working

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Google scatter chart visualization for the following dataset:

```
Person  Week    Production
------  ----    ----------
Bob      1      3
Bob      2      3
Bob      3      6
Bob      4      2
Bob      5      0
Bob      6      4
Sue      1      7
Sue      3      6
Sue      4      8
```

So what I would like to see is Week along the hAxis and Production along the vAxis.  Each person, live data could be more than 2 people, would have their own plot point color and show up in the chart legend.

Can anyone show me how to do this?  I find the Google documentation/examples lacking for the Scatter Chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/XR48j/

You'll note that I've inserted `null`s where Sue didn't have data.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the data format so I didn't have to worry about inserting nulls where needed.  Thank you though!